# Trouble Converting Apostrophes in JSON response

Tags: python, json

I have a response from an API returned in json format.  It looks as follows:

```
page = requests.get(link)
page_dict = json.loads(page.content) 
print page_dict

>> {u'sm_api_title': u'The Biggest Mysteries of Missing Malaysian Flight MH370', u'sm_api_keyword_array': [u'flight', u'plane', u'pilot', u'crash', u'passenger'], u'sm_api_content': u' Since the plane&#039;s disappearance early Saturday, revelations about the passenger list and plane&#039;s flight plan have left officials scrambling to decipher new complicated clues. The most dangerous parts of a flight are traditionally the takeoff and landing, but the missing jetliner disappeared about two hours into a six-hour flight, when it should have been cruising safely around 35,000 feet. The last plane to crash at altitude was Air France Flight 447, which crashed during a thunderstorm in the Atlantic Ocean en route from Rio De Janeiro to Paris. A day after the flight disappeared the biggest question authorities are asking is did the plane turn around and why? The first officer on the flight was identified as Fariq Hamid, 27, and had about 2,800 flight hours since 2007.', u'sm_api_limitation': u'Waited 0 extra seconds due to API limited mode, 89 requests left to make for today.', u'sm_api_character_count': u'773'}
```

As you can see the response comes back with characters like `&#039;` which are included in the response.  What is the best way to clean this response?

I've used xmllib before and gotten it to work, but when I use it with django it gives me deprecation warnings.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unescape the strings in order to decode the HTML characters. You can unescape HTML strings using the standard library:

```
import HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
unescaped_string = parser.unescape(html_escaped_string)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!  You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Just to add in case someone needs it.  You'll still need to replace '\' escape characters.  I'm using the following: unescaped_string.replace("\\'", "'") and unescaped_string.replace('\\"', '"')